# Django implicit field naming for class with query expression - how does it work?

Tags: python, django, django-models, django-queryset, django-filter

Simplified example of what I wrote today:

```
class Grandparent(models.Model):
    text = models.CharField(max_length=5, choices=too_many)

class Parent(models.Model):
    grandparent = models.ForeignKey(Grandparent, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    info = models.CharField(max_length=30)

class ChildSomething(models.Model):
    parent = models.ForeignKey(Parent, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    data = models.CharField(max_length=5, choices=chromosome_identities)
```

Given a specific Grandparent object, I wanted to order Parent objects underneath it by most ChildSomething's each Parent has, which I did successfully below.

```
grandparent = Grandparent.objects.get(id=32923) # arbitrary id

# This query produces the desired result
parents = (
    Parent.objects.filter(grandparent=grandparent).
    annotate(num_child_somethings = Count('childsomething')).
    order_by('num_child_somethings')
)
```

My question:
**Why** is it Count(**'childsomething'**) **instead of** Count(**'child_something'**)?  The latter was my intuition, which was corrected by a helpful Django error message:

```
Exception Type: FieldError
Exception Value:
Cannot resolve keyword 'user_translation' into field. Choices are: id, translate_text, translate_text_id, translation, usertranslation
```

The answer to this is likely simple, I just couldn't find anything in the docs related to this.  **How does the naming convention work?**  If anyone knows of the **appropriate Django docs link that would be ideal**.  Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Why is it `Count('childsomething')` instead of `Count('child_something')`?

Django makes use of the [**`related_query_name=…`** parameter [Django-doc]](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/models/fields/#django.db.models.ForeignKey.related_query_name) to specify a relation in reverse. If you thus specify `related_query_name='child_something'` in the `ForeignKey` of `ChildSomething` named `parent`, then this would have worked.

If you do not fill in a value for the `related_query_name=…` parameter, then Django will look for the [**`related_name=…`** parameter [Django-doc]](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/models/fields/#django.db.models.ForeignKey.related_name) which is also used to access relations in reverse.

If both are not filled in, Django will automatically construct a value for the `related_query_name=…` parameter, which is the name of the class where the `ForeignKey` is defined in lowercase, so for `ChildSomething`, that is simply `childsomething`.

If you thus want to specify this with `child_something`, you should override the `related_query_name=…` parameter or the `related_name=…` parameter when you construct the `ForeignKey`.

Comment: Thanks for this response, those links were helpful.  

Is there anywhere in the docs that specify what you mentioned, that the default is "the name of the class where `ForeignKey` is defined in lowercase" ?  I can't find anywhere this is stated, and wouldn't have figured it out on my own without the error message.  Am I missing something?

Comment: From the [docs](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/models/options/#default-related-name) it states: `The name that will be used by default for the relation from a related object back to this one. The default is <model_name>_set.`

This seems ambiguous at best, and confusing because of the `_set` appended.

Comment: @Joshua: no that is the `related_name`, you are confusing the `related_name` with the `related_query_name`. The related name is used to access the `ChildSomething`s of a *single* `Parent` object: so with `some_parent.childsomething_set.all()`, but this is *not* used to make queries.

Comment: @Joshua: as is specified for the `related_query_name`: "The name to use for the reverse filter name from the target model. It defaults to the value of related_name or default_related_name if set, **otherwise it defaults to the name of the model:**"

Comment: Thanks for clarifying, I missed that.

Apologies if this is trite, but how would I know that model name is in all lowercase? Is this a general python and/or django convention? I'm trying to learn how to learn from the docs here.

Comment: @Joshua: this is the PEP-8 style guideline https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0008/

Comment: From PEP-8:
`Class names should normally use the CapWords convention.
The naming convention for functions may be used instead in cases where the interface is documented and used primarily as a callable.`

`Function names should be lowercase, with words separated by underscores as necessary to improve readability.`

Thus it looks like django made the decision that it wasn't necessary for the default `related_query_name`.

**Method names and instance variables** `Use the function naming rules: lowercase with words separated by underscores as necessary to improve readability.`

Comment: @Joshua: the class name is in PerlCase, but the `related_name`, `related_queryname`, etc. follow the method and attribute convention.